# Chrome + Content-Encoding: gzip + Basic Auth = Zipped output

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, gzip

Got a weird scenario. Have a website, running over HTTP, protected by Basic Auth (provided via Nginx), it also sets the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header on the root document.

Now this is all good and pretty vanilla, expect for when I enter my username/password into the prompt, it accepts the credentials but gives me back gzipped output instead of the actual, rendered HTML I need. I've tried removing gzip, it works. I've tried removing Basic Auth, it works. Together it doesn't and gives the output below.

[image: gzipped output]

I've also tried it out in Firefox which correctly renders the page HTML (ie. it unzips it before rendering) so to me it looks like it could be an obscure Chrome bug. This website is for an internal only service heavily tied to chrome, needs to be running only over HTTP to make use of iframes without erroring.

Any tips or tricks, can't seem to find anywhere this is happening before unfortunately.

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: I have the same problem with a Java Servlet application behind Apache (Debian). The error occurs only immediatelly just after entering username+passwort in the prompt for the HTTP authentication. When I reload the page, it's displayed correctly. And with Firefox or IE11 the error does not occur. It's an old application and the error did not occur in the past. Did you find out anything in the meantime?